# Sefer on the chagim/moadei Hashana

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, chagim-holidays

Looking for a sefer that discusses the energy that's in the world at every time period throughout the Jewish calendar (so each month and each chag). Which sefer can I turn to for this info? Ideally one with English as well

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but the Bnei Yissaschar for each month discusses "מהות החודש", e.g. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%90

Comment: R Akiva Tatz' [Shabbat and the festivals](https://akivatatz.com/shabbat-and-the-festivals/) discusses these concepts a lot, generically across all holidays. An excellent book even if >half of the content is on Shabbat

Answer (score 1):

You might like [The Wisdom of the Hebrew Months.](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20wisdom%20of%20the%20hebrew%20months&rlz=1CAWITB_enUS1021US1021&oq=the%20wisdom%20of%20the%20hebrew%20months&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigATIKCAIQIRgWGB0YHjIKCAMQIRgWGB0YHjIKCAQQIRgWGB0YHjIKCAUQIRgWGB0YHtIBCDU2ODhqMGo3qAIAsAIA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't discuss every month but it does the main ones, Nissan and Elul. I highly recommend L. Etzot. It has a section Moadei haShem which summarizes all the practical points about the times, from L. Moharan.

Below is a timely example.

There's an English translation called "Advice" translated by R' Avraham Greenbaum.

Chanukkah

1. Through the mitzvah of Ner Chanukkah he recognizes Kavod Hashem Yithbarakh (H"Y glory or presence), and His Kavod is elevated and aggrandized in the world, and those who were distant are awaked to return to Hashem Yithbarakh, and they attain Awe and Shalom Bayith and prayer, and strife and slander are nullified, and universal peace is drawn to all the worlds. (LM #14)

א. עַל־יְדֵי מִצְוַת נֵר חֲנֻכָּה מַכִּיר כְּבוֹד הַשֵּׁם יִתְבָּרַךְ וְנִתְעַלֶּה וְנִתְגַּדֵּל כְּבוֹדוֹ בָּעוֹלָם, וּמְעוֹרְרִין הָרְחוֹקִים לָשׁוּב לַשֵּׁם יִתְבָּרַךְ וְזוֹכִין לְיִרְאָה וְלִשְׁלוֹם בַּיִת וְלִתְפִלָּה, וְנִתְבַּטֵּל הַמַּחֲלוֹקוֹת וְלָשׁוֹן הָרָע, וְנִמְשָׁךְ שָׁלוֹם הַכְּלָלִי בְּכָל הָעוֹלָמוֹת (יד)

2. Through the mitzvah of lighting Ner Chanukkah one draws on himself the Holy Consciousness which is the aspect of shemen ha'tov/ the oil of the Good [Ps. 133:2], which is the aspect of remembrance, namely to constantly remember `alma d'atei/ the Coming World, in general and in particular. [See Memory #4] (LM #54)

ב. עַל־יְדֵי מִצְוַת הַדְלָקַת נֵר חֲנֻכָּה מַמְשִׁיכִין עַל עַצְמוֹ הַדַּעַת הַקָּדוֹשׁ שֶׁהִיא בְּחִינַת שֶׁמֶן הַטּוֹב, שֶׁהִיא בְּחִינַת זִכָּרוֹן, דְּהַיְנוּ לִזְכֹּר תָּמִיד בְּעָלְמָא דְּאָתֵי בִּכְלָל וּבִפְרָט [עַיֵּן זִכָּרוֹן אוֹת ד] (נד)

...

Contents of the book include:

```
32 MOADEI HASHEM -- Shabbat
33 Rosh Chodesh
34 Three Festivals
35 Nisan and Passover
36 Omer and Shavuot
37 Three Weeks
38 Elul
39 Rosh Hashana
40 Yom Kippur
41 Sukkot
42 Chanukah
43 Purim
```